# What is the bulletin character in HTML?

Tags: html, character

I want have some bulletin characters in my HTML page. I do not want to use `<ul> <li> or <ol>` tags.

Can anyone share what is the character format that should have bullet format.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are asking how to get the bullet symbol, take a look here:

- http://natural-innovations.com/wa/doc-charset.html

Using `&bull;` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

ascii code `&#8226;`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for • and the HTML entity is `&bull;`.